# Eclipse e4 RCP syntax coloring rules from File

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, text-editor, text-coloring

What would be the optimal solution to implement syntax coloring for a Text Editor (Eclipse E4 RCP) where the words to be colored are about 1200 at least.

My intention is to create a file to be stored in a folder inside the application installation directory.

Then, by means of an OSGI service read the file and return IRule[] to the SourceViewerConfiguration:

The OSGI service shall be something similar to:

```java
public interface IRulesLoader {
    public IRules[] loadRules(String path);
}
```

and

```java
public class RulesLoaderImpl implements IRulesLoader {
    @Override
    public IRules[] loadRules(String path) {
        //Read the file or whichever method to obtain IRules[]...
    }
}
```

Then, at the Text Editor Part (which extends SourceViewerConfiguration) set the rules:

```java
scanner.setRules(iRulesLoader.loadRules(path));
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810087/eclipse-e4-rcp-sourceviewer-syntax-coloring) shows an example about where to include the above line.

In case that OSGI services are good option to load the file:
How can I read the file at runtime from the installation directory (when released) and at developing time from the project (workspace) folders?

Comment: An alternative might be to define an extension point so the rules can be defined in a plugin.xml

Comment: Ok, for using a plugin to define the rules.
 
Then, how can I read a file (with the IRules words) at runtime from the installation directory and at developing time from the project folders?
  
I gess I'm looking for something similar to what it's done with 'plugin_customization.ini' file for preferences.
 
Thanks very much

Comment: I don't know of any way to distinguish a test run from a product run. The plugin_customization.ini is in a plugin and no special handling is required. I think you will have to have a program argument to tell your code to do something different - or always have the file in a plugin.